# Resolving 404 Error Despite JavaScript and CSS Files in the 'dist' Folder on GitHub

Tags: github, deployment, github-pages

I'm currently grappling with a perplexing issue while attempting to update and deploy my React website. The heart of the problem lies in the 404 error that I'm encountering, which is preventing my website from functioning properly. Strangely, this error seems to be related to the connection of essential files like JavaScript and CSS, even though these files are already present within the "dist" folder on my GitHub repository.

To address this issue, I've tried various strategies, including running the `npm run deploy` command, which does successfully upload the changes to the gh-pages branch on GitHub. However, despite this successful deployment, my website remains broken, and the 404 error persists.

My page: [text](https://lizzietse0617.github.io/React-erikt-education/)

[The error shows I failed to connect files(javascript,CSS), which they are already inside my "dist" in github.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEYMv.png)

[Here is my package.json and the structure of the react page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkFTs.png)

Here's a snippet from my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "homepage": "https://LizzieTse0617.github.io/Erik-website-react/",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, insights, or solutions to help me resolve this perplexing issue and restore the functionality of my React website. Thank you very much!!!

I have tried `npm run deploy` and confirm the changes are updated to the gh-pages in github: [text](https://github.com/LizzieTse0617/React-erikt-education/tree/gh-pages)